# Setting up BasicTex (Homebrew)

Tags: pdftex, packages, mactex

Just getting started with TeX and I think I'm missing something...

I've installed BasicTex via Homebrew Cask (`brew cask install basictex`) which supposedly includes pdfTeX and a bunch of other tools (MetaFont, dips, MetaPost, etc.), but when I run pdflatex I get 'Command Not Found'.

Is there additional setup required here? (`tlmgr`?)

(On Mac OS X 10.11.4)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and install BasicTeX or MacTeX 'directly' (no Homebrew involvement).

Comment: Welcome! I thought Homebrew had sensibly decided not to provide TeX packages any more, but it appears that's unfortunately not so.

Comment: Install [the whole thing](https://tug.org/mactex/mactex-download.html) directly from tug.org -- it's 2.5G bytes but it's worth it.

Comment: @cfr For the most part, that's true, but it's still available through Homebrew Cask - which downloads the package anyway. They still have one, but it's patched to hell and only 32-bit, so there's that

Comment: @JosephWright I'm leaning in that direction. Even trying things out for ~30 minutes proves to me that unless you're really familiar with how the TeX environment works, a GUI for configuration is a *really good* idea

Comment: "install Mactex" is only for those who hate having disk space or a small number of files on their system.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**Update:**

As noted by [Dorian](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/401439/108715), `brew cask` is now smart enough to run the installer:

```
$ brew install --cask basictex
==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-20180417.pkg
==> Downloading from http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-20180417.pkg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying SHA-256 checksum for Cask 'basictex'.
==> Installing Cask basictex
==> Running installer for basictex; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.
Password: <prompts for password>
installer: Package name is BasicTeX-2018
installer: Installing at base path /
installer: The install was successful.
  basictex was successfully installed!
```

Again, however, the newly installed binaries won't be in your `$PATH` until you open a new terminal window or new login shell.

```
$ which pdflatex
$ pdflatex
-bash: pdflatex: command not found
$ bash --login
Restored session: Thu Nov 29 10:19:33 PST 2018
$ which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

---

**Original answer (2016-07):**

`brew install --cask basictex` just downloads the `.pkg` installer, which you then need to open so it can install itself.

```
$ brew install --cask basictex
==> Tapping caskroom/cask
Cloning into '/usr/local/Library/Taps/caskroom/homebrew-cask'...
remote: Counting objects: 3781, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3728/3728), done.
remote: Total 3781 (delta 73), reused 627 (delta 32), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3781/3781), 6.51 MiB | 666.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (73/73), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Tapped 1 formula (3,747 files, 15.4M)
==> Creating Caskroom at /usr/local/Caskroom
==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-20160523.pkg
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask basictex
==> Running installer for basictex; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are ignored.
Password:⚿
==> installer: Package name is BasicTeX-2016
==> installer: Installing at base path /
==> installer: The install was successful.
  basictex staged at '/usr/local/Caskroom/basictex/20160523' (105M)
```

You can see where it was download ("staged") at the end of the `brew cask` output (as above); locate in the Finder and double-click, or just use `open`.

```
$ ls /usr/local/Caskroom/basictex/20160523
mactex-basictex-20160523.pkg
$ open /usr/local/Caskroom/basictex/20160523/mactex-basictex-20160523.pkg
```

[image: BasicTeX installer window]

If you now try to find, say, `pdflatex` in the same Terminal window, it won't be in your `$PATH`:

```
$ which pdflatex
$ pdflatex
-bash: pdflatex: command not found
```

Open a new one, however, and you'll find it in `/Library/TeX/texbin`.

```
Last login: Fri Jul 15 08:35:43 on ttys001
$ which pdflatex
/Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex
```

And you're good to go.

Comment: if you found this - like me - because you are trying to generate pdf with pandoc, you need to also run `sudo tlmgr install collection-fontsrecommended`, and maby several more `tlmgr` commands to install all the packages your specific template needs

Answer (score 6):

I installed [BasicTex](http://www.tug.org/mactex/morepackages.html) but it was not added to the PATH file in macOS. I use zsh so i added the following to `~/.zshrc`

```
# pdftex
export PATH=“/Library/TeX/texbin/:$PATH”
```

Answer (score 4):

Only `brew cask install basictex` is needed:

```
==> Satisfying dependencies
==> Downloading http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/mac/mactex/mactex-basictex-201706
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Verifying checksum for Cask basictex
==> Installing Cask basictex
==> Running installer for basictex; your password may be necessary.
==> Package installers may write to any location; options such as --appdir are i
Password:
==> installer: Package name is BasicTeX-2017
==> installer: Installing at base path /
==> installer: The install was successful.
  basictex was successfully installed!
```